# query() with Angular $resources always “Undefined is not a function”

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I simply use following code to call query() with ngRecourse, but it always hits “Undefined is not a function”

[demo.js]

```
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngResource']);

app.factory("resourceFactory", function($resource) {
  return $resource("js/demo2.json", {}, {
    'get':{method:'GET'},
    'query':{method:'GET',isArray:true,url:"js/demo2.json"},
    'save':{method:'POST'}
  });
});

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, resourceFactory){
  'use strict';

  var ajax = new resourceFactory;
  ajax.$query(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });

});
```

[demo2.json]

```
[
  {"demo2":"test"}
]
```

[error]

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-resource.min.js:9:466
    at s (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:7:302)
    at d.module.provider.$get.e.(anonymous function).q.then.p.$resolved (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-resource.min.js:9:423)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:112:20
    at l.$get.l.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:125:305)
    at l.$get.l.$digest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:122:398)
    at l.$get.l.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:126:58)
    at l (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:81:171)
    at S (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:85:301)
    at XMLHttpRequest.D.onload (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:86:315)
```

If I use "$get" with simple object return, it works. So I am pretty not sure what is going wrong with my code.

Comment: `resourceFactory.$query` will work why there is new `resourceFactory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be simply `resourceFactory.query` instead of `resourceFactory.$query` & also there is no need to create a instance of object using `new` keyword

**Code**

```
resourceFactory.query(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you try do promise on an Array.

I got the same issue and put the WebService array wrapped in a JSON
  ie:

```
{ list: myArray })
```

instead of:

```
myArray
```

and works as a charm!

I use the same version of angularJS, and the undefined is looking for the push methods.

I just found the issue on GitHub [Issue 56](https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy/issues/56) and it's still open!

Comment: Only, if you have access to the API,